# How to import chartist in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chartist.js

I am trying to use charts from chartist.js link: https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html#simple-line-chart

When I try to use them in my code I am getting Chartist to defined how can I import it in my component ?

Code:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import chartistGraph from "react-chartist";

const simpleLineChartData = {
          labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
          series: [
            [12, 9, 7, 8, 5],
            [2, 1, 3.5, 7, 3],
            [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
          ]
}

class Chart extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
            <chartistGraph data={simpleLineChartData} type={'Line'} /> 
      </div>

    )}

}

export default Chart;
```

Above code gives error saying Chartist not define. How to import some library and use it in reactjs.

Comment: Did you try importing the library? var ChartistGraph = require('react-chartist') try this. It will include chartist library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run

```
npm install react-chartist --save
```

One more thing, you need to install chartist also as it is the dependency

```
npm install chartist --save.
```

Then you will be able to import Chartist into your application.

```
import chartistGraph from "react-chartist";
```

Here is the link how it can be implemented in codesandbox.
[codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/2wyk3q1jmp)

Follow this link for the implementation [Link](https://fraserxu.me/react-chartist/)

Comment: I have updated my code check it out but I am getting error: Can't resolve `chartist`

Comment: have you restarted the server, you need to that.

Comment: this seems to be wrong as `ChartListGraph` is another library.

Comment: @Manoj I want to use this -> https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/index.html but couldn't find how to import it in reactjs. Any code would be helpful reagrding how to use it in react component https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html#stacked-bar

Comment: @stack26 I want to use this https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/index.html is it same or different.

Comment: it's a default import ,  you can give any name to it. react-chartist is the wrapper around chartist js. It is the same thing

Comment: @stack26 I resstarted the server but still same error.

Comment: now follow the new instruction that is mentioned and restart ther server. It should definetly work

Comment: @stack26 I tried as you mentioned but still giving error please see the imgur images https://imgur.com/a/LfePWsP of each of my files. Please check those 4-5 screenshots. I am adding `Chart` component inside my `App` component.

Comment: yes install chartist also npm install chartist --save, I have mentioned in the answer. and restart the server it will work. I cannot see chartist as dependency in your package.json. thats the reason its not working

Comment: @stack26 Check that package.json see it is there 2nd line in dependencies.

Comment: That is react-chartist, you need to install chartist also. react-chartist is just the wrapper around chartist

Comment: run as i mentioned in the answer

Comment: There is permission issue man run you terminal as administrator. Run as administrator. then you should be able to install it. run agian that command in adimintrator envvironment https://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/. Install tself didn''t happen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172513/discussion-between-stack26-and-stone-rock).

Comment: @stack26 I finally solved it check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702740/i-am-getting-error-while-installing-node-modules-on-windows-7#

Comment: @stonerock great!!. Congrats

Comment: @stack26 Can you please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50733529/how-to-use-plugins-with-chartist-js

Answer (score 1):

You can import ChartistGraph from 'react-chartist' as:

```
 import ChartistGraph from 'react-chartist';
```

or

```
var ChartistGraph = require('react-chartist')
```

Also, 'react-chartist' doesn't include the css files for Chartist, so if you want to add the styles then add this in your index.html file:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css">
 <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js</script>
```

Or you can install 'chartist' package

```
 npm install chartist
```

[See this link for decription](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartist)

Comment: Is it same as this one -> https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/index.html or is it different.

Comment: Yes, it is same as this