# I am getting error while installing node modules on windows 7

Tags: node.js, reactjs, chartist.js

I am installing `react-chartist` and `chartist` on my windows 7 machine.

I am using following commands in my CMD:

1) `npm install react-chartist --save`

2) `npm install chartist --save`

But I am getting error please check screenshot below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error seems pretty clear, you must install the specified peer dependency (ajv) yourself

Comment: @Derek So should I do `npm install ajv`

Comment: You should. Also, definitely suggest thoroughly looking at the error before posting, sometimes it can be ambiguous but often times, it isn't

Comment: @Derek Check my updated question new screenshot.

Comment: Again, the error is telling you that you don't have permission, as the current user, to execute the operation. "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator"

Comment: @Derek I am navigating to my react project folder and on right click I open CMD and it opens as ADMIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i found out npm@5.4 has an issue on Windows.
Please try downgrading to 5.3 and see if that works for you.

```
npm install npm@5.3 -g
```

Comment: I will check it now by downgrading and will let you know.

Comment: Thanks man works like a charm. Almost wasted 5-6 hours on that error.