# ref problems with react and chartist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chartist.js

[How to import chartist in react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692407/how-to-import-chartist-in-react-component?answertab=active#tab-top)

I've followed the instructions listed in the above link for integrating Chartist.js with a react application but i'm experiencing an error that I haven't run into before.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
require('./index.css');
import Chart from './components/Chart'
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Chart />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

## chart component

```
import React from 'react';
import ChartistGraph from "react-chartist";

const simpleLineChartData = {
          labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
          series: [
            [12, 9, 7, 8, 5],
            [2, 1, 3.5, 7, 3],
            [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
          ]
}

class Chart extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <ChartistGraph data={simpleLineChartData} type={'Line'} />
      </div>

    )}

}

export default Chart;
```

The error im getting is:

Uncaught Error: Element ref was specified as a string (chart) but no owner was set. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You may be adding a ref to a function component
2. You may be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's render method
3. You have multiple copies of React loaded

I'm unsure whats going on as I am not explicitly passing ref to any of my components in my code sample. I dont have multiple copies of React loaded to the best of my knowledge. Can anyone help?

Comment: what is the version of react? does it match the version used by Chartist? can you reproduce using http://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: The version is react@16.6.3. Not sure about version used by Chartist, i didnt see anything about react version compatibility on https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartist.  And havent heard about stackblitz but will try there

Comment: in Stackblitz i get this error Error in /turbo_modules/react-dom@16.5.0/cjs/react-dom.development.js (55:15)
Target container is not a DOM element.            Link to stackblitz editor is : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lgsv88

Comment: working stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rvory5?file=index.js